# Disappearing Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails keeps losing reference one of my controllers. If I restart the server, it will return, then after a bit of navigating, I'll get the uninitalized constant Controller error again...

I've never seen this error before.

Here's a dump of the rake:

```
admin_teams GET       /admin/teams(.:format)               admin/teams#index
POST                  /admin/teams(.:format)               admin/teams#create
new_admin_team GET    /admin/teams/new(.:format)           admin/teams#new
edit_admin_team GET   /admin/teams/:id/edit(.:format)      admin/teams#edit
admin_team GET        /admin/teams/:id(.:format)           admin/teams#show
PATCH                 /admin/teams/:id(.:format)           admin/teams#update
PUT                   /admin/teams/:id(.:format)           admin/teams#update
DELETE                /admin/teams/:id(.:format)           admin/teams#destroy
```

Here's the routes:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :team_members
  resources :organizations
  resources :users
  resources :teams
end
```

the controller:

```
module Admin
  class TeamsController < Admin::AdminController
    def index
      @teams = Team.all
    end
  end
end
```

the views:

[image]

** Update ** 
Here's the log trace:

```
ActionController::RoutingError - uninitialized constant Admin::TeamsController:
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:270:in `const_get'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:270:in `block in constantize'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `each'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `inject'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:266:in `constantize'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:93:in `controller_class'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:44:in `controller'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
  airbrake (6.0.0) lib/airbrake/rack/middleware.rb:52:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
  web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
  web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
  railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
  railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
  railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
  rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
  railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
  puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
  puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
  puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
  puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
  puma (3.6.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: The guidelines say that it is better if you can provide a code snippet instead of a screenshot to share code.

Comment: I understand, I did share both. I can add the controller code in text if that helps...

Comment: Can you paste the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Two suggestions: You can try `spring stop` and `rais s` again. Also, make sure that `teams_controller.rb` is in `app/controllers/admin/teams_controller.rb`

Comment: yes, rails s starts it again or heroku restart. But, that's not an option in production.

Comment: uninitialized constant TeamsController

Comment: can you give the logs from a single request to the server? You can get it with `heroku logs`

Comment: I added the request error trace, the same thing happens on localhost.

Comment: In your routes file, you have a `resources :organizations` that seems to load fine. What does the OrganisationsController look like? Does the TeamsController follow the same pattern: same folder, `s`/no `s` at the end of the file/class name, same way to declare `Admin` module at the begining of file ?

Comment: Yes, every other controller in the admin folder has the same structure and works fine...

Comment: I should add, there are some custom routes happening. For example, at root level there are routes like this  get '/teams/:team_id/schedule', to: 'schedules#show_default' and they do not map to a teams_controller.rb on the root because there isn't one

Comment: I wonder if just manually writing the routes would solve this instead of using resources